# Can I configure Google Vision to recognize vulgar fraction symbols (e.g. ½, ¼, etc...)?

Tags: google-cloud-vision

When I run [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gJ0e.png) containing various vulgar fraction symbols through the [Google Vision demo](https://cloud.google.com/vision/), it recognizes all of the characters correctly except for those symbols. The same is true when I consume the API whether it be with TEXT_DETECTION or DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION. Is there some way I can configure Google Vision to accurately recognize these symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Vision API** doesn't have a specific configuration to detect this kind of characters. The **OCR** feature has been developed to perform text recognition; however, in some cases, the fraction symbols are not identified as characters, making the service to get wrong values or even they don't recognize the symbols themselves.

Based on this, I have run some tests by using [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtT2t.png) and I could confirm that the service was able to [recognize several fraction symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JC9tL.png) correctly. Keep in mind that Vision API use **machine learning models** that are being trained constantly in order to improve the results quality.

I suggest you take a look on the [Supported Images](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/supported-files) document where you can find some `file format` and `image sizing` recommendations that may help you to improve your results accuracy, as well use the **Send Feedback** button located at the lower left and upper right corners of the [Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/) public documentation in case you want to provide your opinion about the product.

Comment: Unfortunately higher resolution images didn't fare any better for me, but I did submit feedback to them so hopefully they'll take that into account later.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In this case, you may try to use other font formats in order to check if it helps you to improve the results accuracy as well as review the [Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/release-notes) documentation of Vision API to keep the track of the new features and functionalities added to the service.